# Hadoop Namenode without HDFS storage

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, biginsights

I have installed a hadoop cluster  with total 3 machines, with 2 nodes acting as datanodes and 1 node acting as Namenode and as well as a Datanode.
I wanted to clear certain doubts regarding hadoop cluster installation and architecture.
Here is a list of questions I am looking answers for----

1. I uploaded a data file around 500mb size in the cluster and then checked the hdfs report.
   I noticed that the namenode I made is also occupying 500mb size in the hdfs, along with datanodes with a replication factor of 2.
   The problem here is that I want the namenode not to store any data on it, in short i dont want it to work as a datanode as it is also storing the file I am uploading. So what is the way of making it only act as a Master Node and not like a datanode?

I tried running the command hadoop -daemon.sh stop on the Namenode to stop the datanode services on it but it wasnt of any help.

1. How much metadata does a Namenode generate for a filesize typically of 1 GB? Any approximations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to conf directory inside your $HADOOP_HOME directory on your master. Edit the file named *slaves* and remove the entry corresponding to your name node from it. This way you are only asking the other two nodes to act as slaves and name node as only the master.

Comment: Thanks for this info, but i tried removing the name of Masternode from Slaves file and it wasnt helping to achieve this. I also tried updating slaves file on every node (datanodes ) and remove the Namenode entry , still not helping. 
Then i finally tried to make an exclude file which would decompression the datanode on the namenode which was taking way too long.

Comment: you restarted the cluster after removing the entry right?

Comment: yes I did try restarting the cluster but it didn't do the required thing.
Only thing which helped was to create a exclude file and decompress the datanode services on the namenode. This solved the problem. Though after this Zookeeper & BigSql conf. files got corrupted, I had to delete them and let the namenode make them all over again.